# NodeJS versions to connect Postgresql database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm

I need to connect the datebase in Postgresql with my nuxt project. However, when I try to use the extension pg, the system breaks;

This is a small example that i am triyng to do and to test if the connexion works properly;

```
actions: {
        getResult() {
            const Client = require('pg').Client
            const cliente = new Client({
                user: "?",
                password: "?",
                host:"127.0.0.1",
                port: 5432,
                database: "teste"
            })
        }
```

But when I put this code the following errors appears

```
These dependencies were not found:                                                                                                                           friendly-errors 10:48:08
                                                                                                                                                             friendly-errors 10:48:08
* dgram in ./node_modules/native-dns-cache/lookup.js, ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/server.js                                                                friendly-errors 10:48:08
* fs in ./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js, ./node_modules/native-dns/lib/platform.js and 2 others                                                          friendly-errors 10:48:08
                                                                                                                                                             friendly-errors 10:48:08
To install them, you can run: npm install --save dgram fs
```

Ok then, if I get it rigth, I need to install the fs and dgram extension; But when I do npm i 'extensions' I received the errors:

For npm i fs:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'dns@0.2.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 0.10.0 < 0.11.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.18.1', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'hawk@0.10.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.18.1', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'hoek@0.7.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.18.1', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'tomahawk@0.1.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 0.8.0 < 0.11.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.18.1', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

added 1 package, and audited 1999 packages in 12s

121 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

52 vulnerabilities (2 low, 10 moderate, 34 high, 6 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

for npm i dgram

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'dns@0.2.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 0.10.0 < 0.11.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.18.1', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'hawk@0.10.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.18.1', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'hoek@0.7.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.18.1', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'tomahawk@0.1.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 0.8.0 < 0.11.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.18.1', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

up to date, audited 1999 packages in 6s

121 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

52 vulnerabilities (2 low, 10 moderate, 34 high, 6 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Is this a error with the version os npm and node, rigth? Do I need to change my npm version to make it run? Is it recommended? Or there is a better way to install this extensions?

Please, help me giving some light ;)

Comment: First of all, these are not errors but warnings.  Not sure where these references come from, because they are *really* old and deprected, but I doubt, they are somehow required by the `pg` package ...

Comment: I see. But when I mark as a comment the function getResult() above it works properly. But of it I supposed the package pg is requiring it